# Como determinar se string é valor estritamente decimal?

Tags: c#, regex, valor-monetário

Gostaria que se a string tiver a vírgula (como nos usamos no real brasileiro para representar as casas decimais), ela retorne `true` e caso não tenha, retorne `false`.

Exemplo:

```
"1" = false;
"1,00" = true;
"10" = false;
"10,00" = true;
"1000" = false;
"1.000,00" = true;
"10.000.000,56" = true;
"10000000,56" = false;
"10.000,00" = true;
"10000,00" = false;
"10.000.000.000,00" = true;
"10000000000,00" = false;
"1000000000000" = false;
"10000000000.00" = false;
"10,000,000,000,00" = false;
```

Já tentei fazer desta maneira, mas não funcionou:

```
bool valid = decimal.TryParse("1", NumberStyles.Currency, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"), out decimal r);
```

**UPDATE:**

Estou tentando validar a partir do regex [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/U7eBJu/1):

```
var regex = @"^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})+)(?:,\d+)[0-9\/]+?$";

var valor = "1000000000000";

var valid = Regex.Match(valor, regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success ? true : false;
```

Alguma solução ?

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61566/discussion-on-question-by-matheus-miranda-como-determinar-se-string-e-valor-estr)

Comment: `var regex = @"^(\d{1,3}\.)*(\d{1,3}),\d{2}$` [REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/p5YAE9/1).